# Call Magento Soap API without logging in

Tags: magento

Is there a way to bypass login for the soap api call in magento. I just want to display a list of products in XML format based on a filter. The information is public and should not need a login. The extra login is causing the API call to be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

SOAP login is meant to disallow other services from grabbing your site's public data in an easy to use format.

Even though the data is public you may not want others to:

- compete with you on your own products;
- load your server(s) with strenuous operations that might slow the whole site down for users;

Comment: but in this case, it's not others who want to use the data, but it's our own application (Chrome Toolbar app) which wants to access the data. The argument above does not hold here.

Comment: Yes that is true but exposing the API without a login on a public server means that anyone *can* use it.